# Difficulty with proving Stirlings approximation

Tags: limits, approximation, factorial

In the proof that i am reading, the "strategy", that is used to prove stirlings approximation, is to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n  }=1.$$

But a quick check shows that the error between factorial and the approximation does *not monotonically decrease*. So how can we use this limit to show that it's an accurate approximation. In fact, how do we even "proof", an approximation, as we haven't defined "accurate".
Why would $\sqrt{2\pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n$, be a more accurate approximation of $n!$, than for example $(1.0001n)!$

Comment: Are you talking about *absolute error* or *relative error* ?

Comment: The verb is prove, the noun is proof.

Comment: You do not need $\epsilon_n$ to monotonically decrease to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\epsilon_n=0$.

Comment: This is not a strategy, it is a definition of Stirling's approximation.

Comment: What are you talking about? Your formula doesn't say (or need) anything about monotony.

Answer (score 1):

This is an equivalent in the sense of [asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis). Here, accurate simply means that the difference between $n!$ and $\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n e^{-n}$ is much smaller than $n!$ when $n$ tends to infinity. In fact this difference divided by $n!$ tends to zero.

The other aspect of the approximation is that the expression $\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n e^{-n}$ belongs to an *asymptotic scale* of functions that involve only polynomials, logarithms and exponential. In this respect, it can be considered a simpler expression than $n!$ and it can be used to prove other results.